# Making pdf with single pages

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf which has 2 pages in a single page.  I want to make it so that the file has single pages.  What can I do to crop the images so that I no longer have two pages in a single page?

Comment: what images are you talking about? ... please draw a diagram of what you have and what you want to have after the conversion

Comment: I have a pdf with two pages in a single page,  I want to split the pages to get a single page pdf.  I have page 1 and Page 2 on Page 1, page 3 and page 4 on Page 2, etc.

Comment: Try [briss](https://briss.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mutool`, a command line tool based on the [MuPDF library](https://www.mupdf.com/).

```bash
mutool poster -x2 -y1 input.pdf output.pdf
```

The output will have `x` times `y` number of pages for each input page.